# Can a MariaDB account have local and remote access to a database?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have created a MariaDB database user `user`. Looks something like:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select host,user,password from mysql.user;                                                                                                                                                 
+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user  | password                                  |
+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------+
| %         | user  | ***************************************** |
+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------+
```

I can connect to the database from a remote computer using command like

```
mysql -uuser -hdevops.ok -p mydatabase
```

This works as expected. I can login using my password.

When I am on the database server and try to connect with

```
[vagrant@devops ~]$ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uuser -p mydatabase                                            
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I expected the `%` to allow access from all nodes in the network including localhost but it seems this is not how it works.

Is it possible to grant this user local access?

I can create another account of course

```
create user 'myser'@'localhost' identified by '****';
```

This would allow me access to the database but that feels more like a workaround.

**Update**

I now think this is only possible by creating two accounts `'myuser'@'localhost'` and `'myuser'@'%'`

`%` does not include `localhost`. Btw `127.0.0.1` and `127.0.0.2` resolve to `localhost` and as a consequence these are also not matches by `%`.

Doesn't make sense but it looks like this is the way it is supposed to work.

Comment: Yes a host of `%` means that user can login from Any Ip including the local ip

Comment: In that case try `mysql -uuser -hdevops.ok -p mydatabase` from the vagrant vm as well

Comment: I know this is really old stuff.. but I am working on an old MariaDB in a Sangora PBX and your update worked i,e, using a separate (but identical) user one with "%" and one with "localhost" in  mysql.user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` in the host field means any targeted host is possible.

There is one special case, when the database makes a difference between `127.0.0.1` (TCP based connection) and `localhost` which connects to the **local unix socket**.

Consider the db settings `skip-networking` and `bind-address`. See 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/

TCP connections are usually **disabled** by default - this might be different depending on distribution, package used, ...

So when you type the following it should work:

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uuser -p mydatabase
```

References:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file.

You could also use the `--socket` option.